# Setting a Persistent Session Filter on Model Driven App

Tags: powerapps, dynamics-365, dataverse, powerapps-modeldriven, common-data-service

I'm trying to set a session filter for users in a Model Driven app. I have users who need to select a value from an embedded custom page. The selection should then filter all Dataverse records going forward as they navigate across forms and views for the duration of the app session.

I've heard lack of persistent filters is a known issue with CDS, but also that options may exist to create the feature via cookies or leveraging XRM.navigation. I cannot find any actual examples to control cookies or xrm.navigation from an embedded custom page in a model driven app.

I am struggling to prove whether this is impossible, or simply a challenge in finding the right references due to the rebranding of Power Apps in the last couple years from Dynamics365 and Common Data Services.